# JQUERY ajax passing null value from MVC View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

hi guys i'm posting some data to controller using jquery ajax, but i am getting null values in my controller,

**jQuery code is:**

```
$('#registerCompOff').click(function() {

    var compOff = [];
    $('div').each(function() {
        var curRow = {};
        curRow.Description = $(this).find('.reason').val();
        curRow.CompOffDate = $(this).find('.datefieldWithWeekends').val();
        if (curRow.Description != null && curRow.CompOffDate != null) {
            compOff.push(curRow);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.href,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: compOff

    });

    return $('form').valid();

});​
```

`compOff` is not null I have checked that...

**controller is:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterCompOff(RegisterCompOff[] registerCompOff)
        {

            //return View();
        }
```

can you tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: //later edit: he is right, create a key/value list and in the controller place the parameters as the keys

Comment: i'm sending an array..same i specified in controller...

Comment: Given your original code, change in *$.ajax* -> `data: JSON.stringify(compOff)` then add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and finally change parameter name of action controller to `public ActionResult RegisterCompOff(RegisterCompOff[] compOff)`. Model binding should kick off then. It did for me.

Comment: yep that i tried and it worked like a charm..thanks lucask

Comment: lucask post ur comment ans...let me mark it as answer

Comment: Done and done. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your original code, change in *$.ajax* -> `data: JSON.stringify(compOff)` then add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and finally change parameter name of controller's action to `public ActionResult RegisterCompOff(RegisterCompOff[] compOff)`. 
 Model binding should kick off then. It did for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

try this :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.href,
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        data: 
        {
             CompOffList: compOff 
        }
    });
```

and change your controller like this :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterCompOff(List<RegisterCompOff> CompOffList)
        {

            //return View();
        }
```

hope this helps

Comment: well adding this content type give me network error...its not necessary to specify content type..

Comment: i have forgot a very important key/value pair (traditional: true).check again

Comment: are you sure that was a good idea, cause now i'm not getting anything in controller, count is 0 now...why do we need traditional here...BTW

Comment: yes.remove the bind attribute as i did.you need this, for detail check this http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/05/pass-array-from-jquery-to-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: @PiyushSardana you are getting null because you must declare list of RegisterCompOff in you controller action.

Comment: let me check, u want me to change array to list..ok

Comment: have you checked transmitted data with firebug or something like that?

Comment: firbug is on all the tym, i have checked it...compOff has two object in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your r passing javascript object as data wherease jquery ajax method expects a key/value pair list.
Try this

```
data:{Description:compOff.Description, CompOffDate:compOff.CompOffDate}
```

Comment: Sorry missed the point that compOff is an array and u r expecting array in the action

Comment: yea but then i'm wraping up those javascript objects in an array...i have multiple objects there